# Corollary 8.7 in Cox's primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Corollary 8.7 in Cox's primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$: given a number field $K$ and two abelian extensions $L, M$, $L\subseteq M$ if and only if there is a modulus $\mathfrak m$ divisible by all primes of $K$ that ramify in either $L$ or $M$, such that
$$P_{K}(\mathfrak m)\subseteq \ker\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak m}\subseteq \ker\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak m}$$
where $\Phi_{L/K, \mathfrak m}$ is the Artin map $\left(\frac{L/K}{\cdot}\right):I_{K}(\mathfrak m)\to Gal(L/K)$ on the ray class group defined by the modulus $\mathfrak m$.

I understand the proof of the forward direction, but I can't see why Cox's proof of the converse makes sense. Specifically,

> If there is a modulus $\mathfrak m$ such that the inclusions hold, then the kernel of $\Phi_{L/K, \mathfrak m}$ is mapped to a subgroup of $Gal(M/K)$ by the map $\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak m}$, which by Galois correspondence, there is an intermediate field $M/\tilde L/K$. But then applying the first part [the forward direction] to the extension $M/\tilde L$, we get $\ker\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak m}=\ker\Phi_{\tilde L/K,\mathfrak m}$.

I could not see why the two kernels are the same. Indeed, I understand that $I_K/\ker\Phi_{\tilde L}\cong H=\ker\Phi_L/\ker\Phi_M$ and that $\ker\Phi_M\subseteq \ker\Phi_{\tilde L}$ but I couldn't see how to relate $L$ and $\tilde L$. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this was asked a while ago, but I had the same question and I couldn't find an answer online.
Here is my solution:

Let $r_{M/\tilde{L}}:\text{Gal}(M/K)\to\text{Gal}(\tilde{L}/K)$ be the restriction map.
As in the first part, we have $r_{M/\tilde{L}}\circ\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}=\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}}$.
This implies
$$\ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}})=\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}^{-1}(\ker(r_{M/\tilde{L}}))=\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}^{-1}(\text{Gal}(M/\tilde{L})),$$
and therefore
$$\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}(\ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}}))=\text{Gal}(M/\tilde{L})=H$$
since $\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}$ is surjective by Theorem 8.2 (Artin Reciprocity).
We thus conclude that the subgroups $\ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}})$ and $\ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}})$ both contain $\ker(\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}})$, and are mapped to $H$ under $\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}$.
This implies, by the correspondence theorem for subgroups, that $\ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}})=\ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}})$.
Then the uniqueness part of Theorem 8.6 shows that $L=\tilde{L}\subseteq M$, which concludes the proof.